# How to understand slice of struct in golang

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and trying to understand pointer.

```
type TreeNode struct {
    Val int
    Left *TreeNode
    Right *TreeNode
}

queue:=[]TreeNode{TreeNode{}}
node:=TreeNode{Val: 1}
pre:=queue[len(queue)-1]
pre.Left = &node
```

but I find that queue[0].Left is still nil

```
type TreeNode struct {
    Val int
    Left *TreeNode
    Right *TreeNode
}

queue:=[]*TreeNode{&TreeNode{}}
node:=&TreeNode{Val: 1}
pre := queue[len(queue)-1]
pre.Left = node
```

This time the queue[0].Left is not nil

can someone help me understand why it's the case?

it would be great if you can explain it in memory level.

eg:
we have a slice of TreeNode at 0x1001
so what's stored in the address
and how the slice linked to A TreeNode eg, at address 0x3001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's happening in the first snippet of code:

```
queue:=[]TreeNode{TreeNode{}}
node:=TreeNode{Val: 1}
// Copy last element of slice to local variable pre
pre:=queue[len(queue)-1] 
// Assign field in local variable pre.  The slice element is
// not modified.
pre.Left = &node
```

Here's the second snippet:

```
queue:=[]*TreeNode{&TreeNode{}}
node:=&TreeNode{Val: 1}

// Copy last element of queue to local variable pre.
// pre and the last element of queue have the same pointer
// value (it was just copied) and point at the same node.
pre := queue[len(queue)-1]

// Set the left field in the node that pre points to. queue[0]
// also points at this node.
// This code is syntactic sugar for (*pre).Left = node.
pre.Left = node
```

To fix the first example, modify the slice element instead of local variable pre.  One way to do this is to use a pointer to the slice element.

```
queue:=[]TreeNode{TreeNode{}}
node:=TreeNode{Val: 1}
// Variable pre is pointer to last element in slice.
pre:= &queue[len(queue)-1] 

// Set the left field in the node that pre points to. This
// is the same value as queue[0].
pre.Left = &node
```